# add expires header with bash scripts returns incorrect entry on AWS with s3cmd

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

i am using this bash script to push files to S3:

```
#!/bin/bash


for f in $(find nas/cdn/catalog/drawings \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f)
do
    extension=`file $f | cut -d ' ' -f2 | awk '{print tolower($0)}'` 
    mimetype=`file --mime-type $f | cut -d ' ' -f2`
    fullpath=`readlink -f $f`
    expires="Expires:`date -u +"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT" --date "+1 years"`"
    cache="Cache-Control:max-age=1296000, public"
    s3upload="s3cmd put -v setacl --acl-public --add-header=$expires --add-header=$cache --mime-type=$mimetype $fullpath s3://ccc-public/catalog/drawings/"
    response=`$s3upload`
    echo $response
done
```

but when i look at the file Metadata, everything up to the `,` is being stored, for example:

```
khine@dhegdheer:~$ curl -I http://cdn/EP01.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: 1GtBxWeKYugj+ZhRptIILeY9JLSbHZ1EmjAbN1m7J7oI1vWegAuW3zaileGBHG33l+ExT4JOWE0=
x-amz-request-id: 807D5E8283799C0B
Date: Wed, 10 Dec 2014 16:48:13 GMT
x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs: uid:1000/gname:khine/uname:khine/gid:1000/mode:33279/mtime:1411736563/atime:1411743616/md5:19cbca5ea3f02446f36cae4900dae426/ctime:1414686917
Cache-Control: max-age=1296000,
Expires: Thu,
Last-Modified: Wed, 10 Dec 2014 14:53:01 GMT
x-amz-version-id: Cmu7RgbS1Z5Cvhip.YJtMJfFoVepog_e
ETag: "19cbca5ea3f02446f36cae4900dae426"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 82394
Server: AmazonS3
```

any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Don't stick your command in a string. Just run it directly and quote the expansion of your variables.

Comment: sorry, i did not understand what you mean?

Comment: he means last line should be like `response=$(s3cmd put -v setacl --acl-public ....)`  As a side note, join the 1990's and stop using back-ticks for cmd-substitution ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Don't stick your command in a string. Just run it directly and quote the expansion of your variables. – Etan Reisner